# Displaying a notification with NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip?

Tags: powershell

I had a script a few years back to display a notification on Windows 10 using the `[System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]` class. I tried to use it today and the `ShowBalloonTip()` method doesn't seem to do anything? Here's my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$NotifyIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()
$NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, 'Title', 'Balloon Tip Text', 'Info')
```

This should pop a notification up in the tray but nothing happens?

I've verified that notifications are enabled in the settings. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193866/22146392) mentioning a registry entry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\EnableBalloonTips`), and the `EnableBalloonTips` property didn't exist but I also created it with a value of `1` to enable it but there was no difference.

I tried this on two separate machines--one Windows 11 and one Windows 10, but it didn't work on either.

Most of the search results reference the `Windows.UI.Notifications` namespace and something called "Toast" notifications. But I want to avoid using that since it requires additional dependencies and I know the `NotifyIcon` method has worked in the past.

So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, it seems that in order for this to work the `Icon` property must be set and `Visible` must be `$true`. This code works:

```
$NotifyIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()
$NotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path)
$NotifyIcon.Visible = $true
$NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, 'Title', 'Balloon Tip Text', 'Info')
```

Comment: Toast Notifications have replaced the old style Balloon Tooltip.  If you want to force apps to use the old style balloon tip, you can enable this GPO:

`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer  REG_DWORD EnableLegacyBalloonNotifications (1)`

   Also, remember to call `$NotifyIcon.Dispose()` when you're done.